# How to open Microsoft OneNote's Notebook (Windows's format) in Mac

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I have bunch of OneNote Notebooks created with Microsoft OneNote 2010 (for Windows). I switched to Mac several months ago and learned that Microsoft has Mac version for OneNote. However I couldn't open or import my old Notebooks. How could I do that?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129283/how-to-import-from-onenote-on-windows-to-the-mac-edition-of-onenote

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but try this:

> **Step 1**
>  Open Safari, or your Web browser of choice, and visit SkyDrive.
>
> **Step 2**
>  Log in to SkyDrive with the Microsoft Windows Live account linked to your OneNote Office installation. If you do not have
>   an Office installation, create a Windows Live account for free by
>   clicking “Sign Up Now” next to “Don’t have a Microsoft account?”
>
> **Step 3**
>  Click “Create,” and then click “OneNote Notebook.” SkyDrive opens a new OneNote document that you can edit from the Web
>   browser of your Mac computer.

At this point you may be able to bring them down from skydrive to your Mac

Taken from [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-onenote-mac-61917.html).